# I'd like Python to look into a package first for imports

Tags: python, import, hierarchy

I might just be at odds with Python's way of thinking here, but to me, when it comes to a package (or any project folder system), the contents of a package should *always* be more important than *anything* outside of that package, including `PYTHONPATH`.

Take this hierarchy for example:

```
somewhere/
    foo/
        __init__.py
    bar/
        __init__.py
        foo/
            __init__.py
```

If `somewhere` is in `PYTHONPATH`, and nothing else here is, and in `somewhere/bar/__init__.py` I do a simple `import foo`, I feel `bar` should import its child, `somewhere/bar/foo`, not a total stranger, `somewhere/foo` from the path variable. Path should be where you go if you can't find something right inside your own system.

In my tests, though, it seems that `PYTHONPATH` trumps direct descendants, which would be a shame, because it's a less powerful, less flexible system, and it doesn't properly honor the DAG nature of hierarchies. Children come first, not siblings, and certainly not ancestors or complete, non-relations. However, when I remove `PYTHONPATH`, suddenly it uses the `foo` inside `bar`.

Am I just doing something wrong, or does Python really work this way? Is there something I can do to make it work the way I think it should? If I remove `somewhere/bar/foo`, *then* it can look in the path, but if I explicitly put a `foo` in `bar`, then it should use that, just as an instance variable will override a class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) is about absolute and relatve imports.

As I understood, `from . import bar` would import the right thing. Reading that PEP could help you understanding the different ways of importing modules.

They point out, that absolut imports are the default, because it can be used for everything:

```
import foo
import bar.foo
import sys
```

In contrast to:

```
import ..foo
import .foo
import sys #absolute
```

Comment: Okay, I see the discrepancy now in my thinking. Linux executable paths actually work the way Python is working here. If `import foo` looked in the local directory first, as I was wanting, then you'd never be able to import a built-in `foo`. I guess that's why Linux requires `$ ./script.sh` to run a script in the current directory (I've always wondered). It felt wrong to change folder structure *and* imports, but as it's being versioned anyway, the two will hold together, and it is actually more explicit to specify relative with a dot, so I will concede the point. Thanks for clearing it up.